# Disabling particular days in Flutter CupertinoDatePicker

Tags: flutter, flutter-cupertino

Is there any way to disable/hide particular days of the week in **CupertinoDatePicker**?

For example, I want to disable **Monday**, **Tuesday** and **Friday**.

Comment: Do you mean this https://github.com/wuzhendev/flutter-cupertino-date-picker ? Keep in mind this repo has less than 50 ★ on Github

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not supported at this moment. If you desire that the best option is to fork the implementation and add the pieces you need.

You can find [the picker in the official repository of Flutter](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/date_picker.dart).